# postgresql row level locking test

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently testing row-level locking in postgresql. The version I used is 8.3.23. I checked official document that row-level locking is supported in this version. But I found it's always a whole table lock instead of a row-level one.
Here is what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE test (

        id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

        status  varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO test(status) VALUES('a');

INSERT INTO test(status) VALUES('b');

SELECT * FROM test;

 id | status

----+--------

  2 | b

  1 | a

(2 rows)

Then I open 1 session:

BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;

This session will acquire a lock.

And open another session:

BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;
```

I found the 2nd session will hang there. My question is: the 1st session should only lock those related rows (row with id=1), but it seems other rows (id=2) are also affected. Is there any configuration to make an actual row-level locking in postgresql ? Thanks.

Comment: It's good news that your example works correctly under version 10.1. The 2nd session gives results immediate.

Comment: It should work under version 8.3.23, too. I suspect it's more like a configuration issue.

Comment: I later found the row-level locking works in my another environment, which has postgresql 9.3.4.